# Combine data string & time string

Tags: dataframe, databricks, azure-databricks

How would you do this?
Databricks 4.1, Spark 2.3

You are given a two column dataframe:
1)  ‘`dt`’, string, as shown.
2)  ‘`tm`’ string, as shown.
I added the third column for this post.

Your job is to create column 3, ‘`dttm`’, timestamp, formatting., leading zeros, precision, and time zones are not as important as id correctly combining ‘`dt`’ & ‘`tm`’.

I used PySpark in this post but I am not married to it.

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('2018-06-02T00:00:00','12:30:00 AM', '06-02-2018 00:30:00.000+0000')
    ,('2018-11-15T00:00:00','03:00:00 AM', '11-15-2018 03:00:00.000+0000')
    ,('2018-06-02T00:00:00','10:30:00 AM', '06-02-2018 10:30:00.000+0000')
    ,('2018-06-02T00:00:00','12:30:00 PM', '06-02-2018 12:30:00.000+0000')
    ,('2018-11-15T00:00:00','03:00:00 PM', '11-15-2018 15:00:00.000+0000')
    ,('2018-06-02T00:00:00','10:30:00 PM', '06-02-2018 22:30:00.000+0000')
  ]
  ,['dt', 'tm', 'desiredCalculatedResult']
)
```

I've gone through dozens and dozens and dozens of examples and attempts and so far I don't find that final workable solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split your date string at "T" to extract just the date portion, and then you can combine that with the time string to get a string that represents the actual timestamp you want to create.  Then it's just a matter of converting it to the proper format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, split, lit, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp

dt_tm = concat(split(df1.dt, "T")[0], lit(" "), df1.tm)
df1 = df1.withColumn("dttm", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt_tm, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a')).cast("timestamp"))
```

Comment: Well done.  Even works with None-nulls which I forgot to include in my example dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at the [built-in functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

You want to look at:

```
date_format
to_timestamp
unix_timestamp
from_utc_timestamp
```

A combination of these or other DateTime functions will accomplish your goal. Spark 2.x has robust support for manipulating datetimes, however, if you truly cannot accomplish it using the built-in functions, you can always fallback to the Joda Time Java package.